# Correcting a false negative answer to a 是不是 question

Tags: yes-no-questions

I am having trouble translating the following situation to Mandarin:

Shown an image

[image]

a person is asked: "Is this an apple or not?"/"是不是苹果?"

and for whichever reason they reply: "It is not."/"不是｡ "

How do you correct them: "It *is* an apple." ?

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

Comment: I am more curious about how can anyone say it is not an apple. 

The first thing I would say to them is "Why do you think it is not an apple? Do you know what apple is?" For me , the most important thing is to find out what was the reason for them to not recognize apple

Comment: you could say in this case: 它是苹果。or 它就是苹果。

Comment: Can I omit 它? 是苹果。or 就是苹果。 ?

Comment: @celaeno yes, you can.

Comment: @celaeno Keep in mind that the way you speak is very important in this case. It could sound odd. To be safe, you can say more like 这怎么不是苹果呢？这就是苹果！

Comment: If it's like an answer to a test question, you can say 不對，是蘋果

Comment: Thank you all. Yes @Curiosity, thanks, the context I had in mind is more like a test question.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be much chance of confusion here, because when you respond, you would be using words to indicate correctness, like 對（対）or 錯 instead of 是. So, if they respond to your question with 不是 and then you say 是 there should be no doubt that you are contradicting them, rather than affirming the correctness of their answer. Chinese is more convenient than English in this regard.

So, a few ways to answer:

1. 不對，是蘋果
2. 你答錯了，是蘋果
3. 它就是蘋果
4. 是啊

... or variations on the above.

And, of course, as the commenters mention, for the sake of pedagogy you could find out why they got the answer wrong.

Comment: Thanks @mendosi. I am still disreputable here so cannot do the upvote, but hope somebody does that for me.